# Using cultured buttermilk to introduce cultures to cheese

Tags: cheese-making

I have read recently that you can instead of using cultured developed in a lab you can get cultured buttermilk and use the cultures in that for your cheese making. I'm just wondering how effective this is and whether you can use it in all cheese recipes that call for cultures?